# Javascript tumblr background changing depending on time of day

Tags: javascript, tumblr

Ok so I am trying to change my tumblr theme so that the background changes depending on time of day.
Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20) {
    if (document.body) {
        document.body.background = "http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/daytime_bg.jpg";
    }
}
else {
    if (document.body) {
        document.body.background = "http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/nighttime_bg.jpg";
    }
}

</script>
```

Here is the total HTML so you can see where it goes. Can anyone help me?
http://pastebin.com/LkwvcDKx

Comment: If the code works you can place it anywhere inside the document. Recommendations tend to suggest putting javascript code at the base of the document, before the closing body tag.

Comment: see the problem is, i am adding it into a pre-made theme so i think some of that coding is interfering.

Comment: Could be. I will try and take a look when I can.

Comment: I've got it working with jquery (I did try a pure js solution but it did not work). I will post an answer below. The theme is calling jquery anyway, so hopefully that is not an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, seeing as the theme is already calling jquery I have a simpler jquery solution that works. If you need pre JS then please say (I did try to implement it but couldn't get the syntax right).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
   if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20) {
      $('body').css('background','url("http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/daytime_bg.jpg")');        
   }
   else {
      $('body').css('background','url("http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/nighttime_.jpg")');
   }
</script>
```

I've made a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9JAG4/

Comment: where did you put it in the theme? i still cant seem to make it work.

Comment: It's at the bottom of the file, and just replaced your script I made a test version here:
http://nativecitizenstest.tumblr.com/ 
http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/daytime_bg.jpg and the nighttime image on your site do not seem to exist, but I was able to use images and then swap the logic in the code to make sure the other image loaded.